# Inconsistency with regard to an event in the Resurrection of Freiza Arc and the Future Trunks arc

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

During the ROF arc, we see Gohan powering up to his maximum (to an extent capable of almost of destroying himself), to allow Goku to detect his energy and use the instant transmission and get back from Beerus's world.

In episode 47 right before the Future Trunks arc, while Goku and Picollo are picking lettuce off the field, when Goku tries to go to Beerus's world, we see him not being able to detect Vegeta's energy until he turns SSJB. Him not being able to the first time, when he found out that Vegeta had gone off training on his own makes sense because Vegeta had gotten a lot stronger and it was stated that his ki was completely different. This time around, it didn't. It's obvious base Vegeta was a lot stronger than what Gohan powered up to during the ROF arc.

To top it all off, once Bulma contacts Vegeta and Goku regarding Future Trunks, we see Kid Trunks turning SSJ and barely powering up which was sufficient for Goku to find. Kid Trunks wasn't obviously stronger than Gohan or powered up to the extent Gohan did during the ROF arc. Which again doesn't make sense.

Many might argue that this is because Goku is now used to travelling to and fro and he wasn't then but you have to realise that instant transmission has nothing to do with being familiar with the place. It has to do more with detecting ki.

Is this in general bad writing and inconsistencies? Or is there a particular reason for the above listed events?

Comment: Dragon Ball is full of inconsistencies. Not only Super, also the original. Remember Tien being 4 or 5 levels beyond Semi Perfect Cell and suddenly being able to hold him down with his kikoho

Comment: I agree that was pretty stupid but at least they indicated that Cell hadn't taken any damage. Gohan almost killed himself and it was even stated by Whis and Beerus that the half Saiyan was putting way too much stress on his body. Meanwhile, kid trunks managed to effortlessly powerup to a level easy enough for Goku to find.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it was to show how out of touch Gohan had become with Martial Arts and fighting, that he had to power up to the point of self destruction for Goku to detect him.

It also helps because of the fact that he knew where he had to look for the ki.

Like you, I think it is lazy writing. Like Krillin going up against SSB, however much Goku was holding back, that was just pure bs.